# Get data from mongoDB using node.js, connection works but no data is showing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So i have made an application using node.js and connected it to mongoDB, but no data is showing, it is simply showing and empty json data file []. The database name is **sample_geospatial** and the collection is named **shipwrecks** and all ip addresses are OK to connect with.

Why am i not succeeding with my task to show the data in the browser?

> This is my app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var shipwrecksRouter = require('./routes/shipwrecks');

var app = express();

// Database connect with moongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://gockzor:***********@cluster0-boypg.azure.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function (callback) {
    console.log("Kopplingen lyckades!");
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/shipwrecks', shipwrecksRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});
module.exports = app;
```

> This is my model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var WrecksSched = new mongoose.Schema({
    recrd: String,
    vesslterms: String,
    feature_type: String,
    chart: String,
    latdec: Number,
    londec: Number,
    gp_quality: String,
    depth: String,
    sounding_type: String,
    history: String,
    quasou: String,
    watlev: String,
    coordinates: Array,
}, {
    collection: 'shipwrecks'
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('ShipwrecksModel', WrecksSched);
```

> This is my routes file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ShipwrecksModel = require('../models/ShipwrecksModel.js');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    ShipwrecksModel.find(function (err, wrecks) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        else {
            res.json(wrecks);
        }
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Are you seeing the `wrecks` data if you log it to the console before sending with `res.json`?

Comment: If you're seeing `[]` in the api response rather than an error - then the issue could either be you're not able to connect to proper collection or proper db where your collections exists, So from your `dburl` you've got connected to `test` but is that your  db where your collection `shipwrecks` exists ? If not the try to switch to actual db or replace test in url with actual db..

Comment: Replace test in your mongoose url with your db name which is sample_geospatial

Comment: Thanks for the quick replys, it was that simple :) I copied the connection string directly from mongoDB, did not realise i had to specify the database in the url :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting it as an answer :

If you're seeing `[]` in the api response rather than an error -

> then the issue could either be you're not able to connect to proper
>   collection name(if you're sure collection has data in it) or correct db where your collection exists.

**So from your DB url :**

```
'mongodb+srv://gockzor:***********@cluster0-boypg.azure.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

You've got connected to `test` DB, So is that your DB where your collection `shipwrecks` exists ? If not the try to switch to actual DB after getting connected or replace `test` in url with actual DB name.

So by default you'll get an url w.r.t. to `test` db when you get it from Atlas mongoDB. So replace it on url once in all or you can switch it over the code after connecting to DB, using `useDb` function. **Ex. :-**

**From code a basic way to switch DB ::**

```
 async function myDbConnection() {

    const url = mongodb+srv://gockzor:***********@cluster0-boypg.azure.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

    try {
        await mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
        console.log('Connected Successfully')
        mongoose.connection.useDb('myDB'); // Switching happens here..
        /**
         * Do some DB transaction with mongoose models as by now models has already been registered to created DB connection
         */
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error connecting to DB ::', error);
    }
}
```

**Or you can have something like this directly in url ::**

```
const dbUrl = mongodb+srv://gockzor:***********@cluster0-boypg.azure.mongodb.net/myDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```